# Pointer address in c++

Tags: c++

I apologize in advance for the silliness of this question. But I couldn't find the way of understanding this outcome. I'm trying to figure out what the pointer really is in C++. Following is just a simple code printing an address in different ways.

```
int a = 15000;
char *b = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a); //equivalent of char *b = (char *)a
int *m = &a;

//(1)
printf("&a:%p\n",&a);           //0x7fff5fbff878
printf("&*m:%p\n",&*m);         //0x7fff5fbff878
printf("m:%p\n",m);             //0x7fff5fbff878

//(2)
printf("a:%p\n",(int*)a);       //0x3a98
printf("&*b:%p\n",&*b);         //0x3a98
printf("b:%p\n",b);             //0x3a98
printf("*m:%p\n",(int*)*m);     //0x3a98

printf("&b:%p\n",&b);           //0x7fff5fbff870

printf("&m:%p\n",&m);           //0x7fff5fbff868

//(3)
std::cout << "b:" << b << std::endl; //error: Segmentation fault: 11
```

So the question is

- why the address of (1) and (2) are different
- why the size(length of address) of (1) and (2) are different
- what happened when an int is cast to a char*
- how 'b' could contain an address of 'a'
- why the error (3) has occurred while 'printf("b:%p\n",b)' is working.

Comment: Hint: 0x3a98 == 15000

Comment: Apology accepted. In case (2) an int is converted to a pointer. This is legal but not warranted to have sense in arbitrary context. In case (3) you try to use this fake pointer as if it points to char array (C string) - but it does not.

Comment: Damn, Thanks a lot for not blaming :P

Comment: The length of (1) and (2) aren't different, it's just that leading zeroes aren't printed.

Comment: Thanks. how about (3)? Why doesn't it print 15000?

Comment: (3) expects the `char*` to point to a zero terminated string. It doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the address of (1) and (2) are different

Because in the first example (1), you use the `&` address of operator, which gives you the address where the "a" variable is stored, example `0x50302040`.

But the second example (2), you are using the value that address (`0x50302040`) points to, which returns 15000 which equals to 0x3a98 in hexadecimal.

> what happened when an int is cast to a char*

If `int` has a value of 15000, now `char*` points to the address `15000`, which is clearly wrong.

> why the error (3) has occurred while 'printf("b:%p\n",b)' is working.

Because your pointer is a `char*` pointer, therefore the **character sequence** overload `(ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);` is used, and since your pointer doesn't point to a character sequence (in fact, it doesn't point to anything since you assigned an invalid value to it), your program crashes.

Theres a `ostream& operator<< (void* val);` overload that will just print the address of the pointer, but you need to explicitly cast your `char*` pointer to a `void*` pointer to use it:

```
std::cout << "b:" << (void*)b << std::endl; // Prints 0x3a98 (15000)
```